# counter for string search in another string

Tags: java

I want to search how many times a string appear in another string 
It does not work correctly when i put an similar string at the end.

```
public class C3_Project3_WPr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strn1="AliAliAli";
        String strn2="AliAliSinaAli";
        String strn3="Ali";
        int count1=StringCounter(strn1, strn3);
        System.out.println(count1);
        int count2=StringCounter(strn2, strn3);
        System.out.println(count2);     
    }
    //ُString in String Method
    static int StringCounter(String str1, String str2){
        int counter=0;
        if (str1.isEmpty() || str2.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        for(int i= 0; i<str1.length(); i++){
            if(str1.contains(str2)){
                counter++;
                str1= str1.substring(str2.length());
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: `contains` doesn't specify *where* the substring was found, so simply removing that many characters from *beginning* doesn't necessarily remove the found substring. Use `indexOf` instead of `contains`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to your problem is here**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String strn1 = "AliAliAliwewdwdweAli";
    String strn2 = "AliAliSinaAliAlAli";
    String strn3 = "Ali";
    int count1 = StringCounter(strn1, strn3);
    System.out.println(count1);
    int count2 = StringCounter(strn2, strn3);
    System.out.println(count2);

}

// ُString in String Method
static int StringCounter(String str1, String str2) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (str1.isEmpty() || str2.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = str1.indexOf(str2); i >= 0; i = str1.indexOf(str2, i + str2.length())) {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When modifying `str1` you only take in to account the length of the search string, but ignore the index in which it was found. Fixing this (e.g., by using `indexOf`), will fix your results too:

```
int index = str1.indexOf(str2);
while (index >= 0) {
    counter++;
    index = str1.indexOf(str2, index + str2.length());
}
```

Comment: Don't waste space and time chopping off the found substring, just use `indexOf(str2, index + str2.length())` to continue the search after the found substring.

Comment: @Andreas good point - should've remembered that existed. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Loop can also be written as a `for` loop: `for (int i = str1.indexOf(str2); i >= 0; i = str1.indexOf(str2, i + str2.length())) { counter++; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive method: It's quick and easy way to solve your problem:

```
static int StringCounter(String str1, String str2){
    return (str1.contains(str2)) ? 1 + StringCounter(str1.replaceFirst(str2, ""), str2) : 0;
}
```